# Variables not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

The problem lies within the block:

```
check_sort(l.begin(), l.end(), "list");
time_insert(insert_list, data);
check_sort(s.begin(), s.end(), "set");
time_insert(insert_set, data);
check_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), "vector");
time_insert(insert_vector, data);
```

The error states that the variables are not declared in the scope, but shouldn't l,s,v be universal variables here? What am I doing wrong.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef void Inserter(vector<double>);

vector<double> gen_data(int num_elts);
void insert_list(vector<double> data);
void insert_set(vector<double> data);
void insert_vector(vector<double> data);

void time_insert( Inserter inserter, vector<double> data);

template <class Iter> bool is_sorted(Iter first, Iter last);
template <class Iter> void check_sort(Iter first, Iter last, string cont_kind);

int main() {
    srand(time(0));// initialize random number generator
    cout << "How many elements for container? ";
    int num_elts = 0;

    while (cin >> num_elts) {
    if (num_elts <= 0)
        cout << "Error, should be > 1";
    else {
        vector<double> data = gen_data(num_elts);

        check_sort(l.begin(), l.end(), "list");
        time_insert(insert_list, data);
        check_sort(s.begin(), s.end(), "set");
        time_insert(insert_set, data);
        check_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), "vector");
        time_insert(insert_vector, data);

    }
    cout << "\nHow many elements for next container? ";

    }
    return 0;

} 
void time_insert( Inserter inserter, vector<double> data) {
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    if (t1 == clock_t(-1)) { //if clock() doesn’t work
    cerr << "sorry, no clock\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    inserter(data);
    clock_t t2 = clock(); 
    if (t2 == clock_t(-1)) {
    cerr << "sorry, clock overflow\n";

    exit(2);
    }

    cout << "Elapsed time: " << fixed << setprecision(2)
     << double(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds\n";

}

class Larger_than { 
    double v;
public: 
    Larger_than(double vv) : v(vv){}
    bool operator()(double x) const {return x>v;}
};

// Sorts and then inserts data into a list
void insert_list(vector<double> data)
{
    list<double> l;
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
    list<double>::iterator p = find_if(l.begin(),l.end(), Larger_than(data[i]));
    l.insert(p, data[i]);
    }
} 
// Sorts and then inserts data into a list
void insert_set(vector<double> data)
{
    set<double> s; 
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
    set<double>::iterator p = find_if(s.begin(),s.end(), Larger_than(data[i]
                          ));
    s.insert(p, data[i]);
    }
} 
// Sorts and then inserts data into a list 
void insert_vector(vector<double> data)
{
    vector<double> v; 
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
    vector<double>::iterator p = find_if(v.begin(),v.end(), Larger_than(data
                                        [i]));
    v.insert(p, data[i]);
    }
} 

// generate num_elts random numbers in the range [0.0, 1.0), 
// which are returned in a vector

vector<double> gen_data (int num_elts) 
{
    vector<double> result; 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elts; i++) {
    double datum = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX; 
    result.push_back(datum);
    }
    return result;
}

// is container spanned by [from, last) sorted?  
template <class Iter> bool is_sorted(Iter first, Iter last)  
{  
    Iter next = first;                   // next element  
    for (next++; next != last; next++, first++) {  
    if (*first > *next)  
        return false;  
    }  
    return true;  
}  

// prints a msg describing container kind, as well as whether container  
// spanned by [from, last) is sorted  
template <class Iter> void check_sort(Iter first, Iter last, string cont_kind)  
{  
    cout << "Check: " << cont_kind << " is ";  
    if (!is_sorted(first, last)) cout << "not ";  
    cout << "sorted\n";  
}
```

Comment: `l`,`s` and `v` are stack variables in the functions you declare them. They do not exist outside the scope of those functions.

Comment: "shouldn't l,s,v be universal variables here?" No, and I don't have even the faintest idea why you would expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

How should `main` know about `s`, `l` and `v` at all? They're local variables of completely unrelated functions (the `insert_xxx` ones), there's no way `main` could know about them. If you want to make them globally accessible, just make them global variables, i.e., put their definition before `main`:

```
// ...

list<double> l;
set<double> s;
vector<double> v;

int main(){
  // ....
}

// ...
```

Comment: Well, yes. ;P But it at least works for what s/he wants to do. Of course I could talk all day about dependency injection, but ... lets keep it simple, no?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like l is defined in the 'insert_list' function and would not available in main.  Only variables defined insider your function are available.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have declared the variables at all. Why do you think they should exist in main? There are no globals or locals with those names anywhere that I can see. Try declaring them before using them.

Comment: There are locals, in the `insert_xxx` functions.

Comment: @Xeo: Locals in a function aren't visible in main. You need to make locals in main, or make them globals.